# Does $.each() execute for one item?

Tags: jquery

Will the jQuery method $.each() execute if there is only one item in the array?

At least for me, it isn't.

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: Are you sure it's an array?

Comment: Yes, but without seeing your code we can't do much for you other than say yes.

Comment: Yes it does. Can you show your code? Something else must be wrong. Keep an mind a single item is not an array, it's just an object. `$.each("somestr")` is different than `$.each(["somestr"])`

Comment: >11k rep and you don't include any code or relevant information?

Comment: Yep we need some code to help here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will. Example.

```
var one = [1]; 
$.each(one, function(index) {
    alert(one[index]);
});
```

will alert 1

Comment: Why doesn't that work when the source is http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/10?

Comment: @4thSpace - because that's not an array.  That's an anonymous object.  Arrays use bracket syntax.